# Extremely basic division equation not working in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can't get this to divide into a decimal.  It is rounding to value 0.

```
    private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double x = 0;

        x = 1 / 2;

        ans.Text = x.ToString();
    }
```

When I debug, x is zero before it is sent to the textbox 'ans.'

I tried..and string variable is still zero..

```
double x = 1/5;

string displayX = x.ToString("0.0000");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Division_of_integers) and those are the expected outputs.

```
double x = 1.0 / 5;  // this will not perform integer division
double x = 1/5;  // this does  (1/5 = 0).  
double x = 1D / 5; // this will not because 1 is treated as a double
```

Comment: I knew it was gonna be something simple lol.  It worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: I give this answer a `D` for not giving the correct suffix for a Double Literal.

Comment: @ConradFrix:  Thanks but I'm actually not using any suffix so on that criterion I fail miserably (so the D is way too nice).

Comment: @AustinSalonen well you nicely explained why its 0 and `D` is the correct suffix for a double literal so I was trying to be funny. So much for that :P

Comment: @ConradFrix:  whoosh to me...  ha!

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of the follow:

```
double x = 1;
double y = 1.5;

double ans = x / y;
```

Comment: I don't see the value of using `Convert.ToDouble()` in this instance. It might even confuse readers if they replace x/y with ints (as the OP did).

Comment: updates/edits in response to a comment is always worth an upvote in my book :)

Comment: plus, you can always have an upvote for saying I'm right, regardless of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Replace double x = 1/5 with double x = 1.0/5 and that should fix it. Because both numbers you're dividing are integers, it still processes it as an integer, rather than as a double. When you think through logically, it makes some sense - it does the division in whatever form those numbers are and then saves it to the variable; the variable type is inconsequential to the actual equation.

(I realize there are other answers already, but hopefully this will help you see why the issue exists.)